# How to stop SpecFlow from displaying timing information

Tags: specflow

How can I configure SpecFlow so that it does not display timing information as part of the test text e.g.

> -> done: Steps.ThenIWillBeDeniedAccess() (0.0s)

Cheers.
Jas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I need to put this in the `app.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow"/>
  </configSections>
  <specFlow>
    <language feature="en-GB" />
    <unitTestProvider name="nUnit" />

    <trace traceSuccessfulSteps="false" traceTimings="false" />
  </specFlow>
</configuration>
```

The key setting here is `traceSuccessfulSteps`, setting that to `false` did the trick.